# graphics in C for learning

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I want to develop some graphical application in C using gcc compiler on Linux. 
Which graphics library shall I use to start with? How can I start developing graphics appication on Linux using C?

Comment: Do you mean like 3D graphics? or a User Interface?

Comment: @Jack Maney: that would be cool :)

Comment: @BlackBear: there's libaa for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about straight graphics look at:

- [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)
- [GGI](http://www.ggi-project.org/) (very simple)

If you are talking GUI, [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) would certainly be your best bet.

Comment: I want it very simple initially. The same way how it was done using Turbo C when I started learning C :)

Comment: Hmmm, Qt is a lot, but it's definitely not C. SDL is C and good, so, +1-1=0 from me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

SDL -- http://www.libsdl.org/

Very straightforward to use, and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure C (vs C++), there's SDL: [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), a standard in C library.

If you like C++, there's also SFML: [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index-fr.php)